# Can I charge my AT7-C8 Toshiba tablet with an inexpensive USB charger instead of a Toshiba brand charger?

Tags: wi-fi

I don't want to spend 30.00 on a USB wall charger if I don't have to. Can a cheap USB charger work to charge my AT7-C8 Toshiba tablet?

Answer (score 2):

Possibly you can use a cheap charger, but it depends on the tablet as well as the charger.

Many cheap or OEM phone chargers give a low Amperage charge, from 400mA (milli amperes) to 1000mA. However, since tablets have a much larger battery, charging from a low amperage charger will cause the tablet to charge very slowly.

Most tablet USB chargers are designed to give a higher Amperage, in the range of 1000mA to 2000mA. They are generally bulkier due to the electronics needed to properly give more power. And it is also why they are more expensive.

Some tablets aren't even able to get a charge from low Amp chargers. For example, Apple's iPad will detect that you have plugged it into a charger, but it will say `not charging` if the charger doesn't have a high enough Amperage.

Basically, your tablet may reject cheap chargers, or it will charge very slowly. Check the `mA` spec of the cheap charger you are looking at; if it is below 1000mA (1A), it will likely either charge very slowly or it won't charge at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's highly NOT recommended. Despite of voltage and amperage, this cheap chargers doesn't have the same components. Some of this components regulate the tension, electrical oscillations and etc. Some of them are very expensive, so, the manufacturers decide to leave it out to achieve a cheap price. Your tablet may show some troubles with this type of charger. You can use another (good) brand, but avoid use this cheaper charger.

Answer (score -1):

Sure can! Even old BlackBerry chargers work fine.

Answer (score -1):

Of Course yes(but not recommeded), it will work but if you are using a cheap/duplicate/non-standard usb wall plug then surely it will damage the phone.Damage in the sense like even if u removed the charger it will show charging, touch wont work while charging, annoying notification "High Voltage" while charging please unplug - these things can damage your phone board if you are not cautious.